# How to set a custom image size for single product image for a specific category in woocommerce ( prior to 3.0 )?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set a custom product image size for a specific category of products in woocommerce. The default is set to 300x300 px in woocommerce single product image settings but need it to be 600x600 px for specific category of products.

Comment: you can add an extra image size - and then create a template for that product category in which you use that image size

Answer (score 0):

Use Theme support codes in your functions.php files

```
<?php add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
'single_image_width' => 322,
) ); ?>
```